# How to insert 't->'  after '\n'?

Tags: ruby

I have a string that might have some of `\n` before the actual text. I want to add `t->` after the new line character or characters. That means that once there is something else than '\n' in the string I want to insert 't->'.

Is there any simple way than

```
what = "\nrufus: ready"      #result is "\nt->rufus: ready"
#what = "\n\nrufus: ready"   #result is "\n\nt->rufus: ready" 
#what = "\n\nrufus\n: ready" #result is "\n\nt->rufus: ready\n"

what.length.times do |i| 
    if (what[i,1] != "\n")
        what.insert(i,"t->")
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: "\n\n".length is always 2. Is your code doing what you want it to do? And what is `what`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. It would be more helpful if you would include your original text and what you want to get. You want to insert some text before all the end of lines?

Comment: "What" ain't no variable I ever heard of. They have newlines in "What"?

Comment: Sorry guys. I had the code ready and didn't replace variable `what` with my string everywhere in my sample code :-( Updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, you want the following;

- "abc def" => "t->abc def"
- "\n\nabc def" => "\n\nt->abc def"

As such, I'd try;

```
string.sub(/^\n*/) do |newlines|
  "#{newlines}t->"
end
```

Comment: Would you code work for `\n\nready\n` where I expect `\n\nt->ready\n` as a final string?

Comment: @radek, this looks for any preceding `\n`s (there can be none), then passes the match `\n*` into the block, and replaces it with "#{$1}t->". Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert some text at the end of every line:

```
original = "Hello\nWorld\nYay"
changed = original.gsub /$/, ' More!'
puts changed
#=> Hello More!
#=> World More!
#=> Yay More!
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to change the string as you iterate over it.

Presumably this is what you're looking for?

```
"\n\n".gsub("\n", "t->\n") # => "t->\nt->\n"
```

(substitute every instance of "\n" with "t->\n")